# Get size of window of a different application using java

Tags: java, window

Is it possible to get sizes of all the open application windows using java?

Say for example I have 3 windows open on my laptop right now.. (google chrome, Microsoft word and Counter Strike in windowed mode)

So is it possible to get the dimension of each window size along with the running application name?

Comment: You'll need a JNI/JNA based solution, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java) for example

Comment: I tried the code http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091597/4794952
but when I run the code I get an error
         The type com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I downloaded the jar for stdcalllibrary from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna324sourcesjar.htm

But even after I am getting the same error

What am I doing wrong?

I searched the error online but didn't get any appropriate solution

Comment: Did you download and link the JNA libraries?

Comment: Yes
I downloaded the libraries from 

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna324sourcesjar.htm

and 

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330platformjar.htm

Comment: And they are in your classpath for your project (also, you might want to include the error somewhere)

Comment: I tried the suggested method in the answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2123192/4794952

Eclipse does not find SessionFactory. Is it a problem? However it does find Configuration.

Comment: Yes I have added both the JARs in the buildpath using add external JARs.                                        The error I am getting is                                                                              (StdCallLibrary cannot be resolved to a type)
on line                                                                                               [public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary { ]                                  and also  (The type com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files)

Comment: Okay, I download the `jna-platform-4.1.0.jar` and `jna-4.1.0.jar` from [GitHub](https://github.com/twall/jna), pasted the code from the linked example (linked the Jars into my IDE (Netbeans)) and ran it without an issue...I don't use Eclipse :P

Comment: I got it fixed :)
Used http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna325jar.htm instead of http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna324sourcesjar.htm

Comment: It's looking for a Window with the title `Document - WordPad` ... You might want to change that to what ever you're looking for ;)

Comment: Yes figured it out just after posting the comment. :P Thanks :)